# ModelState.IsValid is false due to the "required" navigation property in Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, required, modelstate

The `Required` annotation in a Navigation Property in *LessonQuestionDetails*  **Entity-model**, which enables **Cascade-delete table creation through code-first approach**, is causing `ModelState.IsValid` to become `false`. Is there a workaround to set cascade delete without the `Required` annotation.

**Entity-model**

```cs
public partial class LessonQuestionDetail
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int LessonID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int QuestionNumber { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public byte ChoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public string Choice { get; set; }
    public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }

    [Required]  // Sets the CASCADE constraint, while creating table
    public virtual LessonQuestion LessonQuestion { get; set; }
}

public partial class LessonQuestion
{
    public LessonQuestion()
    {
        this.LessonQuestionDetails = new List<LessonQuestionDetail>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<LessonQuestionDetail> LessonQuestionDetails { get; set; }
    //Other code
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditLessonQuestionDetails(LessonQuestion lq)
{
    SQLContext context = new SQLContext();
    int intChoiceNum=1;
    var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors); // There are errors
    var valid = ModelState.IsValid;  // sets False
    // Other code
}
```

Comment: You don't need Required field. You can do that with fluent API. You will find many reference on google

Comment: **What** are the errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the fluent API.

Something like below should work but might require tweaking as wrote it on the editor and didn't test it but that's the gist of it

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     modelBuilder.Entity<LessonQuestion>()
        .HasOptional(c => c.LessonQuestion)
        .WithOptionalDependent()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
 }
```

But, it's a bad design to use the Entity Framework models with your API directly.

You should use view models for the properties required by your API then map them to your Entity Framework models. Never expose the Entity Framework model directly as it only leads to problems and changing your Entity Framework model will require application wide changes including the applications that use the API which becomes a nightmare to maintain.